# Passing context in one file to a function defined in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

First file, `utils.js`, has a function which imitates a `shell` so that the user can enter javascript code :

```js
const readline = require('readline-sync');

var x = {
  shell: function(){ 
    while(1) {
      let code = readline.question(">> ");
      try {
          console.log(eval(code)); 
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = x;
```

Second file, `main.js` uses the above `shell` function :

```js
const utils = require('./utils.js');

var country = "india";
var names = ["x", "y", "z"]
function foo(){...}
function bar(){...}

utils.shell();
```

I've been trying to pass the context of Second file to the `shell` function so that I'd be able to access functions and variables in the Second file from within the shell. But I'm not successful so far.
[image]

I messed a bit with `call` and a few other ways, but they all failed. Any help is highly appreciated..

NOTE:
`utils.shell.call(this)` is passing an empty object `{}` to the `shell` function

Answer (score 2):

In the above in main.js, you have declared the variables using var. So it wont set these in **this** context. So I have rewritten the code in such a way that,

main.js

```
const utils = require('./utils.js');

country = "india";
names = ["x", "y", "z"];
foo = function (){

}
bar = function (){

}
utils.shell.call(this);
```

and utils.js

```
const readline = require('readline-sync');

var x = {
  shell: () => { 
    while(1) {
      let code = readline.question(">> ");
      try {
          console.log(eval(code)); 
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = x;
```

Now in the utils you won't get the empty object rather than will get all four members **( foo, bar, country, names).**

Answer (score 1):

Could you put everything in an object, pass it as an argument to `utils.shell`, and have `utils.shell` expose it on `global`?

```js
const context = {
  country: 'india',
  names: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
  foo: () => console.log('foo')
}

utils.shell(context);
```

```js
shell: function(context){
  Object.assign(global, context); 

  while(1) {
    let code = readline.question(">> ");
    try {
      console.log(eval(code)); 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```